# Automatically sync changes in SQL Databse and android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-server, android-asynctask

I have created an SQL Database which stores the link of an image/video file. This Database is accessed by my android application and then the image/video file is displayed on all devices running my app.I also created a web page with php and html so that the Admin can select a particular file and upload it to server,the webpage just creates the link of the file and stores the link in my database. 
My problem is that my android application needs to refresh at every particular interval to check whether the link has been changed or not. I use AsyncTask to retrieve JSON values from my SQL Database and in AsyncTask,I display the file in OnPostExecuteMethod.

Is there a way that my android app sends network requests only when there is a change in the server SQL database?
I looked up and found FCM but didn't find a way to store data in the firebase database using php.If this is possible,please guide me to a good tutorial.

Otherwise I created another object of my asynctask class but I cannot compare the values  of these two objects. Do you have any ideas as to how can i compare the values obtained by two objects of same asynctask class?